# Running a Java program using Selenium's WebDriver on another computer

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, executable-jar

I have made a Jar file for a test programm using Selenium's WebDriver.

I just have to run this Jar file (with selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar in the same folder) on my computer and it works fine.
But when I try to run it on another computer using `java -jar test.jar`, I have the following error message :

[image: The error message]

I did create a `Main` class and a correct `public static void main(String[] args)` method in it.

I don't remember installing anything on my computer to be able to use Selenium before. Is there something to do to run this program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I compiled the program with a 1.8 version of the JDK and I was trying to execute it on a previous version of the JRE.

I solved the problem by upgrading my JRE on the other computer.

I did try to use the `-target` build parameter but it seemed not to work with BlueJ IDE (I tried to add this line : `bluej.compiler.options=-source 1.8 -target 1.5` to the `bluej.properties` file).

I'm sorry, the problem had nothing to do with Selenium whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your java version installed on 2 pcs are the same version (very important)

In thise case , you should reinstall java on 2nd pc with the java version installed on 1st pc.

OR

Install latest version of java on 2nd pc

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, You have compiled your files in major java Version and try to run in minor java version. Make sure both machines have same version.